# Как в печатной форме начинать с новой строки?

Tags: c#

Редактирую бухгалтерский отчет, и поставлена задача, чтобы все элементы БЖУ (белки, жиры, углеводы) начинались с новой строки. Подскажите, как это осуществить? Код, который выводит эту позицию `{PriceListTemplateItem.ProductDetail}`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можно больше кода?

Comment: гадание на картах таро идет по отдельному прайсу

Comment: @SelfishCrawler я добавил скрин как это выглядит

Comment: Понятнее не стало.. Только не говорите, что у вас есть БД, где для каждого продукта есть одна колонка, в которой полностью весь текст из красной рамки, а не каждое число в отдельной колонке...

Comment: @SelfishCrawler это программа iiko office, там особо не разгуляешься, есть встроенный редактор и все, и он сам через функции берет данные из номенклатуры товаров

Comment: С таким вопросом следует обращаться в поддержку этого вашего `iiko office`. К языку `C#` ваш вопрос не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: @SelfishCrawler просто может подскажешь что можно попробовать вставить, потому что по факту это c#

Comment: Не очень понятно, где тут C#, потому что кроме полей какой-то мнимой БД через точечку ничего более нет, даже какого-то логически законченного куска кода нет. Вам нужно в вашей базе данных ProductDetails разделить на отдельные колонки, чтобы вывод был примерно такой: "белки - " + {PriceListTemplateItem.белки} + " г., жиры - " + {PriceListTemplateItem.жиры} итд. Ну либо парсить эту строку по пробелам и соединять потом, что уже сложнее и глупо впринципе.

Comment: `белки\r\nжиры\r\nуглеводы` - вывод такой строки будет в 3 строки.